# Is it possible to type a React component Props using a class property decorator?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-decorator

What I would like to achieve is a similar thing to how `@Input` in Angular works (and without specifying interfaces/types as generics). E.g.

```
class App extends React.Component {
 
 @Prop color: string;

}
```

Is it possible to create such a decorator for TypeScript to infer the proptype from it and provide type assertion when I'm using such a component with a JSX syntax?

Comment: Yes, you can do this by typing the props a component takes in. ```type AppProps = {a:number} class App extends React.Component<AppProps, {}>```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

If you are using typescript, you can do something like this:

```
interface Props {
  color: string;
}
class App extends React.Component<Props> {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [react function components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) and [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) you can avoid inheriting React.Component class with type parameters for providing types to your props